# Is this simple VB.NET code valid?

Tags: vb.net

So I made [this](http://myscrambledmind.com/helloworlds.php) and someone has submitted a new VB.NET hello world example:

```
Module m1
Sub Main()
 Console.out.writeline("Hello World")
End Sub
End Module
```

Is this valid VB.NET? I don't know the language, so wanted to check it.

The example that is currently on the website is:

```
Console.WriteLine ("Hello, World!")
```

What I'm mainly questioning is the `Console.out.writeline` - is this right?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.Out.WriteLine` are equivalent.

The documentation for [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb.aspx) says: "*Writes the specified string value, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream.*"

The documentation for [`Console.Out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out.aspx) says: "*Gets the standard output stream.*"

`Console.Out` is a [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) which is used for outputting text to a stream. The documentation for [`TextWriter.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt.aspx) says: "*Writes a string followed by a line terminator to the text string or stream.*"

`Console.WriteLine` is basically just a shortcut for `Console.Out.WriteLine`.

Comment: Is there any general preference? I assume Console.WriteLine for conciseness?
EDIT: I posted this before seeing the edited version of this post. Thanks for the info! Very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. Though the the `Console.Out` property can be set to a stream other than the standard output.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out.aspx):

> This property is set to the standard output stream by default. This
>   property can be set to another stream with the `SetOut` method.
>
> Note that calls to `Console.Out.WriteLine` methods are equivalent to
>   calls to the corresponding `WriteLine` methods.